# Can't get width of images in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have been creating a simple slider where images are moving from right side to the left one. In Firefox browser everything works, but in Chrome I have problem to get width of images.

```
$(window).load(function() {

    //load images from a folder
    for (m = 1; m <= 5; m++) {
        $('ul').append("<li><img src='image_" + m + ".jpg'/></li>");
    }

    //variables
    var ul = $('ul');
        li = ul.find('li');
        ul_width = 0;

    //sum witdh of ul li
    $(ul).children().each(function() {
        ul_width = ul_width + $(this).width();
        alert(ul_width);
    });

...
```

In Chrome, alert shows me value of 50, because I have set `margin-left: 50px` for `img`. So I always get just margin size, not image width as I want to.

But in Firefox everything works without problems. I get margin size and image width, as is expected.

Please, could you suggest me, how to solve this problem? I really don't understand, why the same code works in Firefox but not in Chrome.

Comment: The CSS relevant to those `ul` and `li` elements might be pertinent to the answer here, but as a guess I would check two things - If you use the debugger to set a breakpoint on the line you check `$(this).width()`, are the images not visible/of 0 width due to css at that point? Secondly are the images still loading at that point? You may want to look into $.imagesLoaded to suppress the summing code till they are fully loaded into the dom.

Comment: Agree with @ChrisO'Kelly, I guess images are not loaded yet. One fast fix would be to set the width through css. On your slideshow, maybe all your img has the same width... (I know, this is quick n dirty). The best way would be to preload your images with javascript, and trigger the sum width compute when the load is completed

Comment: When you are appending images those isn't loaded yet. Possibly you need to load images in browser cache then you will able to get its width and height. You can see how preloader works. Quick turnaround for you is to take a look at load function in jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give this a try - it appends the images at the first chance the document is ready and waits to check the sizes when everything has been loaded (including the newly appended elements) :

```
$(function() { // shorthand for $(document).ready();

var ul = $('ul');

for (m = 1; m <= 5; m++) {
    ul.append("<li><img src='image_" + m + ".jpg'/></li>");
}

var li = ul.find('li'),
ul_width = 0;

$(window).one('load', function() {

    li.each(function() {

        ul_width = ul_width + $(this).width();
        alert(ul_width);
    });
});
});
```